# pgfplot: Customize the axis wide scientific notation multiplier

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Hy Guys, 
I'm experiencing two problems with ticklabel formats. First, if I explicitly set `scaled y ticks = true`, the base ten notation still appears at every tick.

Here's the diagram:

[image: Problem Child]

Here the used code for the picture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
scaled y ticks = true,
width=4.52083in,
height=3.56562in,
xmin=0, xmax=0.01,
ymin=-0.0025, ymax=0,
xlabel={Time t [s]},
ylabel={TopNode Displacement [m]},
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
zmajorgrids,
legend entries={$D=0$},
legend style={nodes=right},
scaled x ticks = true,
x tick label style={
rotate=90,anchor=east,},
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,sci,precision=5}]
\addplot [
color=green,
solid,
line width=1.0pt
]
coordinates{
(0,0)(9.9173e-005,-3.01301e-005)(0.000199171,-0.000141203)(0.000299992,-0.000335604)
 ....
(0.0997007,-0.0021914)(0.0998004,-0.00218975)(0.099901,-0.00218216)(0.    
100001,-0.00216898) 
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I dismissed the majority of the coordinate information, otherwise this post would be some 100 lines long.

If this should ever be solved my second question is if there is a way to set the exponent of the axis multiplier to a specific value, e.g. from 10^-3 to 10^-2?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think

```
scaled ticks=base 10:3
```

or similar will solve both problems. You can do `scaled x ticks` or `scaled y ticks` separately, and the number after the colon is the common exponent that you're factoring out.

(Note that this is incompatible with your current `y tick label style`, so you will need to remove that before this works.)

Comment: And to have numbers displayed in 10^3 (instead of 10^-3) `scaled ticks=base 10:-3` can be used.

Comment: @Togh you saved the day!

Answer (score 4):

YES! `scaled ticks=base 10:3` did the thang! 
But I had to remove the line `y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,sci,precision=5}`.

The working code looks like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
scaled ticks=base 10:3,
width=4.52083in,
height=3.56562in,
xmin=0, xmax=0.01,
ymin=-0.0025, ymax=0,
xlabel={Time t [s]},
ylabel={TopNode Displacement [m]},
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
zmajorgrids,
legend entries={$D=0$},
legend style={nodes=right},]
\addplot [
color=green,
solid,
line width=1.0pt
]
coordinates{
...
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thank you so much.