# Labelling the x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        symbolic x coords={-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6},
        xtick=data
      ]

        \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
            (-2,0)
            (-1,730974)
            (0,20059)
            (1,5492)
            (2,729)
            (3,151)
            (4,30)
            (5,5)
            (6,1)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

When the graph is plotted, I get an axis from 0*10^5 to 8*10^5. How may I change the axis so that I get numbers 0 to 800000 instead?

Comment: Please post a [minimial working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9803 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119887 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69981 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29283

Comment: Put `scaled ticks=false,tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},` in the option of `\begin{axis}[...here]`